# different get_rows from the database

Tags: php, database

This is the function im using to show results in the index.php with the style.css correctly done with the li´s and the div´s all that i just want to show in every li the price or the service i want. EXAMPLE: `($_GET_ROW['ID'] = '1', $_GET_ROW['ID'] = '2')`.

```
function products() { $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, servico, preco FROM loja');

 if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0) {
    echo "Não existem produtos a serem mostrados!";
} else {
    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    echo '<li class="l1 i1 column1">';
    echo '<h2>'.**$get_row["servico"]**. '</h2>';
    echo '<div class="basket"><a href="cart.php?adicionar=' .**$get_row['id']='1'**.'">Adicionar</a></p></div>';
    echo '<div class="preco"><em>Preco:</em><strong>'.number_format($get_row['preco'], 2).'</strong><span>EUR</span>';      
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<li class="l2 i0 column0">';
    echo '<h2>'**.$get_row["servico"].**'</h2>';
    echo '<div class="basket"><a href="cart.php?adicionar=' **.$get_row['id']='2'.**'">Adicionar</a></p></div>';
    echo '<div class="preco"><em>Preco:</em><strong>'.number_format($get_row['preco'], 2).'</strong><span>EUR</span>';      
    echo '</div>';
```

**My database:**

```
-----------------------------------
id servico preco 
-----------------------------------
1 Servico Normal 29.5
-----------------------------------
2 Servico Rapido 32.5
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: you want `while($get_row = mysql_fetch_asoc($get)` rather than `if`. As an aside, use the mysqli or pdo libraries. The mysql is in the process of being deprecated.

Comment: ok, but beside that i could i resolve this? right now i dont have time to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need a `while` loop to iterate through the rows like so:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0) {
    echo "Não existem produtos a serem mostrados!";
} else {
    while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    **echo '<li class="l1 i1 column1">';
    echo '<h2>'.$get_row["servico_normal"].'</h2>';
    echo '<div class="basket"><a href="cart.php?adicionar=' .$get_row['id'].'">Adicionar</a></p></div>';
    echo '<div class="preco"><em>Preco:</em <strong>'.number_format($get_row['preco'], 2).'</strong><span>EUR</span>';      
    echo '</div>';**
    }
}
```

However, you should immediately stop using `mysql_` functions as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) and vulnerable to SQL injection; and use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

**Update 1**

`mysql_` functions are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

The principle of my initial answer still remains. You have two rows in your database and you want to iterate through them.

```
while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    $liClass = 'l' . $get_row[id];

    echo '<li class="' . $liClass . ' i1 column1">';
    echo '<h2>' . $get_row[servico] . '</h2>';
    echo '<div class="basket"><p><a href="cart.php?adicionar=' . $get_row['id'] . '">Adicionar</a></p></div>';
    echo '<div class="preco"><em>Preco:</em><strong>' . number_format($get_row['preco'], 2) . '</strong><span>EUR</span>';      
    echo '</div>';
}
```

For the first row, the output would be:

```
<li class="l1 i1 column1">
<h2>Servico Normal</h2>
<div class="basket"><p><a href="cart.php?adicionar=1">Adicionar</a></p></div>
<div class="preco"><em>Preco:</em><strong>29.50</strong><span>EUR</span></div>
```

Comment: ok, but beside that i could i resolve this, right now i dont have time to learn

Comment: You should *really* try to learn it right the first time so you don't have to re-learn it later.

Comment: @Nation This is just from my personal experience. It's a real wake up call after you've been self-taught and then get into the real-word.

Comment: ok njk thank you, i mean it. i will learn it but right now i really need an answer to this, in my future projects i will use  mysqli_ or PDO but right now i really need this.

Comment: oh my mistake i had a while loop not a if.. sorry! either way it doesnt diferenciate the rows... i need something like for example: $get_row['id']='1'

Comment: @Nation I don't quite understand. Could you possibly update your question with the code you're using and a sample result?

Comment: do you see the $get_row´s? in the echo lines?

Comment: @Nation Glad to have helped.